# Where to publish useful customised functions

Tags: 12.04, bash, ppa

I have started to write a customise function, that encapsulates a bunch of actions that make my daily work easier.

A few questions about sharing the function with the community:

- What would be the best way to share the function with the rest of the community?

  1) Simply publish the code on a blog with the instructions to save it to a file, in a certain location?

  2) Create a package and publish it in a ppa?

P.S. the code is in shell script.

Comment: :) thanks. Although I am a software engineer and code all day long, the need of testing and reviewing always seems to slip my mind :). You can go ahead and make your comment an official answer.

Comment: OK, yea having your code tested / debugged is a nice touch.

Comment: If you have a dotfiles project in github, I would post them in a project alongside them.

Comment: @maggotbrain I prefer to host my projects on Gitorious rather then Github because it uses Free Software. Wiki extract: Gitorious is open source and freely available for download and personal use, whereas GitHub is closed-source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would post in in a blog, ask friends to review the script, and once it has been tested a bit / debugged / reviewed, assuming there is sufficient interest, sure you can package it in a ppa.